# Create a subcolumn which will show only at small screen size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to show the subcolumn only at small screen size(col-sm-9).At medium screen size(col-md-2) it wont show.Is there any way to do this?

I have tried in below way but i failed.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-2">
        Level 1: .col-sm-9
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
   body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .col-xs-4 {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .col-xs-8 {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .col-sm-9 {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: question is a little bit not clear, are you trying to make certain div appear in small screens ? and disappear in big screens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use add classes "**.visible-xs**" and "**hidden-xs**" (change the "xs" to the size you want like "lg", "sm"...)

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-2">
                Level 1: .col-sm-9
                <div class="row visible-sm hidden-md">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                        Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Media Queries`, for example, if you would like to make certain div invisible for small screens like mobile, you can use the below code;

```
@media all and (max-width: 658px) {

.col-sm9 { display: none; }

}
```

Or if you would like to have it hidden for larger devices like tablets and laptops, you can try this;

```
@media all and (max-width: 992px) {

.col-sm-9 { display: none; }

}
```

For having a better comprehensive idea about `Media Queries`, check the link below;

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: If i follow the first way then after(min-width: 658 px) .col-md-2 is not showing.